# Open API v3- get rid of type from schema

Tags: java, swagger, schema, swagger-ui, openapi

we are migrating one of our project from swagger v2 to OpenAPI v3 version and we are facing a scenario where the header has no type. i.e., manually updating the generated swagger file for the header with  `“schema”:{}` or  `“schema”:{example:”null”}` or  `“schema”:{nullable:true}`  are working as expected and able to upload those swagger versions in the api portal successfully. So now the question is, while making the same change using swagger annotations such as `schema = @Schema(example = “null”)` or `schema = @Schema(nullable = true)` is generating the `“type”:”string”` by default which looks like `“schema”:{“type”:”string”, Example: null}` or `“schema”:{“type”:”string”,nullable: true}`  which is considering as a breaking change in the api portal. Could anyone please assist on how to get rid of the `type` under schema.

Comment: Could you please format your question to make it more readable? It's a bit difficult to read in its current form.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure you can get rid of the `type` because a schema in JSON Schema is implicitly `type: any`, if no schema is defined. If it's only because you can't have the string `type`, I think the best way would be to manually edit the file.

I don't believe you can have an empty method.

```js
schema = @Schema()
```

Regarding the validity of JSON Schema...

```json
"schema": {}
```

is the same as

```json
"schema": {"type": "any"}
```